# How should I correct an images height and width in java?

Tags: java

I am currently developing a game similar to flappy bird for an AP Computer Science final project, my problem is that I am using the `getBounds` method in the Rectangle class to create bounds on the Bird object and Pole object in order to check for collision. However, I am unable to properly check for collision because the image size for both objects is 400x400 pixels and on a 600x700 Jframe, it says that it is always colliding. The actual object is not 400x400 but the entire image it was imported from is. How can I resize this image so that it properly creates a rectangle around the object? Here is my code for the bird currently:

```
    width = (img.getWidth());
    height = img.getHeight();
    ...
    public Rectangle getBounds(){
    return new Rectangle(X,Y,width,height);
   }
```

Comment: You should take a look at [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Crop the image before using it in Android.

Comment: @Henry not on android, this is for windows

Comment: s/Android/your program/